# function max of symbolic values - matlab

Tags: matlab, max

I have to calculate some limits:

```
syms x1 x2 a
x0 = [0, 1];
x_dir = [1, 0];

f = max(0,x1) + (x1^2)*abs(x2)
f_lim = (1/a) * (f(x0 + a*x_dir) - f(x0))
f_lim_left = limit(f_lim, a, 0, 'left');
f_lim_right = limit(f_lim, a, 0, 'right');
```

I just can't use max function on symbolic values, because I am not allowed by MATLAB. But, it's obvious what I am trying to do: to get a piece of code that's independent of variables (x0, x_dir), so I can change them easily.  I've tried using double or using feval(symengine,'max',x,-y) as found on net, but no luck. Any workaround, guys?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `f` as

```
f(x1,x2) = feval(symengine,'max',x1,0) + (x1^2)*abs(x2);
```

and then compute its directional derivative with respect to `x1` by finite differences as

```
f_lim_x1(x1, x2) = (f(x1+a, x2)-f(x1,x2))/abs(a);
```

You can also look at the `limit` function

```
limit(f, x1, x0, direction)
```

where `direction` can be either `'left'` or `'right'`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't simply follow what you wrote. :) can you be more explicit? In f_lim I need f(x0 + a*x_dir) which is f(a, 1), not f(x1+a,x2) as you wrote. What am I not understanding?

Comment: `f` is a function of two variables, so `x0` is a point (x1,x2). You have to evaluate `f_lim_x1(x1, x2)` where you need it. The direction is instead given by the sign of `a`.